# Replace string after equal sign

Tags: sed

I have a XML file with the following structure:

```
<ns1:ReservationPCC pseudoCityCode="1234" pseudoCityType="Booking" supplierService="Sabre"/>
```

and I would like to replace the pseudoCityCode by let's say abcd.

I'm trying the following:

```
sed -e's/pseudoCityCode=.*/pseudoCityCode="abcd" /g'
```

But, it returns:

```
<ns1:ReservationPCC pseudoCityCode="abcd"
```

Adding a white space:

```
sed -e's/pseudoCityCode=.*\s/pseudoCityCode="abcd" /g'
```

will return the following:

```
<ns1:ReservationPCC pseudoCityCode="abcd" supplierService=Sabre/>
```

Why did the pseudoCityType disappear? What am I missing?

Carlos

Comment: `.*` means `any sequence of characters` so it matches all the way to the end of the line or to the last occurrence of any subsequent character (e.g. `\s` meaning a space in your case).

Comment: Thanks Ed. The sintax is just not very intuitive ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/pseudoCityCode="[^"]*"/pseudoCityCode="abcd"/'<<<'<ns1:ReservationPCC pseudoCityCode="1234" pseudoCityType="Booking" supplierService="Sabre"/>'
```

or like @Ed Morton said:

```
sed 's/\(pseudoCityCode="\)[^"]*/\1abcd/'<<<'<ns1:ReservationPCC pseudoCityCode="1234" pseudoCityType="Booking" supplierService="Sabre"/>'
```

Comment: How do these work, especially the 2nd (Ed Morton) one? Would be nice to learn how it works instead of just copy & paste

Comment: It's called backrefrence. and it refers to a previous part of the matched regular expression (`\1`). you can read more about it here: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html